# How to perform a transitivity mocking of classes/objects in python unit testing

Tags: python, unit-testing, mocking, python-mock

I am new to unittesting in python and was trying to mock a object explained like below:

i have three scripts:

- test1.py (Class : test1)
- test2.py (Class : test2)
- test3.py (Class : test3)

test2.py is creating object of test3.py
test1.py is creating object of test2.py

I want to mock test3 inside test1, so that when it creates object of test2 it consider mocking object of test3.

test3.py:

```
class test3():

    def __init__(self):
        print("Created object os myclass")
        self.name = "rahul"
```

test2.py:

```
from test3 import test3

class test2():

    def __init__(self):
        self.sirName = "Rohilla"
        self.test3object = test3()
```

test1.py:

```
from unittest import mock
from test3 import test3
from test2 import test2

class test1():

    @mock.patch('test3.test3') # -> here i tried __name__+'.test3' but that didn't work
    def fun2(self, myclass):
        mockObject = mock.MagicMock()
        mockObject = {}
        myclass.return_value = mockObject
        test2Object = test2() # -> here test2Object doesn't have mockobject

main1 = test1()

main1.fun2()
```

My problem is test2Object doesn't contain mockedobject for test3. can someone suggest me any other way?

Comment: Please provide a [mcve]. `test3` is undefined in `test2.p`, and whether `test2` uses `import test3` or `from test3 import test3` makes a difference in deciding what actually needs to be patched in `test1`.

Comment: Making `fun2` an instance method of a class `test1` doesn't appear to add anything of value to the question. If you can reproduce your problem with `fun2` being an ordinary function, please do so.

Comment: `mockObject = {}` completely obviates the creation of the `MagicMock` in `fun2`.

Comment: @chepner sorry it was a typo, in test2.py i am importing test3 as from test3 import test3

Comment: @chepner yeah agree to mockObject = {} completely obviates the creation of the MagicMock in fun2. 

Here what i am trying is that whatever value i set for return that should be returned when object of test3 is created, but that is not happening